# Explanation of ambiguous "gokigenyou"

Tags: etymology

I googled for a bit and it seems like ご機嫌よう/ごきげんよう ("gokigenyou") has both a greeting and a farewell meaning, but I couldn't find any etymology to explain it. Does it consist of any simpler parts, or is this a whole word/phrase? Why is it both a greeting and a farewell? I don't think there are other phrases like that but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ごきげんよう** *gokigen'yō*

- [ご](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/71159/meaning/m0u/) (honorific prefix)
- [きげん](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/51333/meaning/m0u/%E6%A9%9F%E5%AB%8C/) ("mood; tide")
- よう (old-fashioned form for よく, a conjugation<sup>†</sup> of [よい](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84#Japanese))

Altogether means "your mood (being) well", or practically "in good mood; in good shape".

> *Why is it both a greeting and a farewell? I don't think there are other phrases like that but maybe I'm wrong about that.*

Well... this word is pretty much analogous in many ways to "Good day!" in English. With the verb omitted, the phrase can stand for both "it is a good day" and "have a good day", thus has dual use as hello and goodbye.

---

<sup>† The inflection of adjectives is normally called *declension*, but in Japanese context I'm more comfortable to call it *conjugation* nevertheless.</sup>