# What is the grammar of ご機嫌【きげん】よう?

Tags: words, syntax, politeness

What is the grammar of ご機嫌【きげん】よう? It is made of three or, we might say, two parts:

<kbd><kbd><kbd>ご</kbd>


<kbd>機嫌【きげん】</kbd>




<kbd>Good spirits
*with honorific*</kbd></kbd>



<kbd>よう</kbd></kbd>

What is よう? Is it 様【よう】 in the sense of "form, style"? Per [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A7%98-2) this word is often a "Noun - used as a suffix".

Would ご機嫌【きげん】よう then be a noun?

Comment: You may find some help at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46578/37097よう . In particular: よう: (old-fashioned form for よく, a conjugation† of よい)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: Although the comment you link is relevant, it would have been tough to find by searching because it has Japanese text.

Comment: This question is the top hit for a search for ご機嫌よう because it is written in a searchable way. Maybe the community would be better off if we re-open it and put an answer here.

Comment: @solidsnack We can edit the old post to improve the searchability (the linked post is now the second result)

Comment: Maybe I misread the search results. If it is second, that is certainly findable.